# 1099-MISC unearned income for dependent

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099-misc

Both my children (1 & 4) received a 1099-MISC for unearned income ($922) from our tribe's gambling profits.  Do they need to be report?

Answer (score 1):

The form 1040 instructions has a section called [Do you have to file?](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798498134304)

Chart B will apply to your kids, and you will see that they do not need to file because their unearned income was less than $1100.